# Flash AS3 Close Browser Window

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, browser, actionscript

Does anyone know how to close a browser window from Flash AS3 that is within an iframe?

Any help/ideas greatly appreciated, Ss888.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done. At least not directly.

What you can do is use the `ExternalInterface` class or `navigateToUrl` to invoke JavaScript.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('Javascript: window.close();'), '_self');
```

At that point, it's up to the browser to prompt or allow/ignore the `window.close()` request.

Comment: many thanks for the reply; unfortunately neither of these methods appear to work (using Moodle Scorm).